# How do I typedef this type in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

```
Foo* (*)[8]?
```

I am trying to treat it as a triple * like so:

```
Foo*** = new Foo* [6][8];
```

but I get mismatched types so I would like to just typedef the actual type but not sure what the notation should be? It's a fixed 6x8 matrix of pointers.

Comment: If you are using C++11 then I would strongly suggest using `std::array< std::array< Foo*, 8 >, 6 >`, and I would also consider replacing `Foo*` with a smart pointer type (such as `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`).

Comment: Ah, pointer roulette... if you see any scary square brackets, throw stars at the problem until the compiler stops complaining.

Comment: I am not though, I tried typedef Foo**[8] foo_t; but then it says incompatible to assign Foo* (*)[8] to Foo**[8] - not sure of the notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer in the first line of the question

```
using Foo2D = Foo*(*)[8];
Foo2D ptr = new Foo* [6][8];
```

Or, if you want to use `typedef`

```
typedef Foo*(*Foo2D)[8];
```

But, don't use either of these. Use a `vector<vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>>`, or `array<array<unique_ptr<Foo>, 8>, 6>` if the size is known at compile time.

If using Boost is an option, there's the [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) library for handling multi-dimensional matrices.

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo *mat[6][8];
```

If it's a matrix of pointers (and not a pointer to a matrix), don't `new` the matrix. Instead, you'll need to `new` instances of `Foo`.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        mat[i][j] = new Foo;
```

Don't forget to delete all your `Foo`s. Better yet, use C++11's awesome `std::unique_ptr` along with nested `std::array`s.

**Edit:** after re-reading your question, you seem to want a dynamically allocated matrix, too. Here is the type of a pointer to such a matrix :

```
Foo *(*mat)[6][8] = new Foo*[6][8];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just break it down like this:

```
typedef Foo *FooPtr;
typedef FooPtr FooPtrMatrix[6][8];

FooPtrMatrix *foo = new FooPtrMatrix;
```